# How to fetch images by their uid's Swift Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to show all images that the current user posts. As you can see in the picture in a table view, every time the current user post an image it automatically creates a unique id for the image under the current user information.

[image: screenshot]

In this images, You will see that when the users post an image it create a node called media for the image with their children.

[image: screenshot]

Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellMe", for: indexPath) as! MyPosttTableViewCell


    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // check if user has photo
    if snapshot.hasChild("media") != nil{
        print("found it")

     //set image locatin
    let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/\("media")"


    FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(filePath).data(withMaxSize: 10*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in

    let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.Myimages.image = userPhoto

    })

    }
    else {
        print("nil")
        }
        })

        return cell


    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a image to a specific ID THEN upload the image to the firebase storage get the image.downloadurl in absolute string and add this value to the key "image" to your object and then post the object to the firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

The media in your users node is stored as a NSDictionary, not as a String. You will have to loop through the media node to get the paths of all your files. You can do something like

```
//Create reference to media directly instead
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("media").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  if let media = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

    //Loop thorugh all the entries in your media node to get all the media paths
    for (_, value) in media {
      FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("media").child(value as! String)

      //get the file now that you have the reference
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: What I am suppose to write under  the for loop ? cell.myimages.image = ?